# how to get the unique value of an array and find the place value?

Tags: javascript

example if I have an array like this:

First Loop

```
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2]
value: 2
placeValue: 10
```

Second Loop

```
[-1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
value: 0
placeValue: 1
```

Third Loop

```
[-1, -1, -1, -1, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
value: 5
placeValue: 4
```

in javascript? the set of array is inside of the loop and the value and the placevalue will always change.

Thanks :)

Comment: Define your problem better. Are you looking for only a value that isn't `-1`? Or are you looking to solve the more general problem of finding a unique value (without knowing what the non-unique values are)?

Comment: do you now whats the value is?

Comment: There is always just 1 unique value?

Comment: the set of array is inside of the a loop and the unique value is always changing.

Comment: Do you want 0-based or 1-based indexes here? You seem to be all over the place. In the first example you have the 11th element (1-based), but in the second you have a 0-based index. And in the third example, you don't even have the right value (unless you are going for -1 based indexes!)

Comment: :( sorry I'm just really confused right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate your arr, place it in a "map", then iterate this one to know wich number is the smaller, then do a indexOf().

Look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shryme/q2kz6/)

I place them like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] in a) {
      a[arr[i]] = a[arr[i]] + 1;
  } else {
      a[arr[i]] = 1;
  }
}
```

When the number is already in the array, I do +1, when it's not there, i just set it to 1.

Then i loop it like this:

```
for (var key in a)
{
    if (a[key] != null && a[key] == 1)
    {
        value = key;
        break;
    }
}
index = arr.indexOf(Number(value));
```

This look at each value in the new array, and if there is one unique (that have 1 as value) i exit the loop and get it's index with indexOf(value);

Then you have your values in the var value and index.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var c = 0; c < arr.length; c++) {   
    if(arr[c] == 2) {
       console.log('value ='+arr[c]);
       console.log('placevalue =');
       console.log(c+1);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know `-1` is the non-unique value.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] !== -1) {
        console.log("value " + arr[i]);
        console.log("position " + i);
        break;    // assuming only one unique value, otherwise leave this line out
    }
}
```

Comment: So it does the same as !=?

Comment: @MattBurland the position should be (i+1)

Comment: @Kevin: Not exactly and you should be careful to know the difference. `!=` will try and convert types while `!==` will not. Generally `===` and `!==` are safer.

Comment: @Hanady: I generally assumed that the OP was confused about indexing in an array and just goofed. In their latest edit they seem to be all over the place on whether they want 0-based or 1-based indexes.

Answer (score 0):

**[try this :](http://jsbin.com/OHUNUvOW/5/edit)**

```
    var g=[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2];

var o={}
var inx=0;
for (var i=0;i<g.length;i++)
{
  o[g[i]]=[ (o[g[i]]?(o[g[i]][0]+1):1),inx++,g[i]];

}

for (a in o)
  if (o[a][0]==1) alert(o[a][2]+' unique at '+(o[a][1])+' count='+o[a][0])
```